# How to call a IdentityServer authorize method to login using WebAPI Controller method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, openid, identityserver3, bearer-token

I'm having a AngularJS client Application and a WebApi to contact the database methods. I'm having an `IdentityServer3` to authenticate the User. How could I login

- **IdentityServer**: `localhost:5005/core/connect/authorize?client_id=ClientA&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30005%2Fcallback&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid&state=94bbc0299da444468bb9cc21e5277cf1&nonce=873ea5f66fe0468faa9a362bf1a50e46"`
- **WebAPI**: `localhost:5000/Auth/Login`
- **Angular App**: `localhost:30005`

How could I authenticate the User via WebAPI login controller method

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Login(UserInfo user)
    {
        // How to implement the logic
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

WebAPI Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "localhost:5005",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "idmgr" } });

        app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
    }
}
```

Kindly assist me how to construct the Login Method in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

first Authority should have protocol. i guess its https. you have to mention protocol in authority. like "https://localhost:5005" in you webapi.

Secondly, i guess (and my personal experience) you should call login from your angular app. I guess you are using angular 2. Please take a look at this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2).
 And when you are making a authorize call from angular app you can include "idmgr" scope( that you have used in your webapi requiredscopes). If you configured to show consent screen this scope "idmgr" will show up there and when you make a call to webapi, its startup method will check if this scope is available and will grant access or return 403(forbidden) access to webapi

Comment: Yes... Its a `https` version only... and I'm using `AngularJs 1.x.x.`
My Question is how to call the `[Authorize]` WebAPI Method using this. Do I need to configure `OWIN` Auth in WebAPI ? If yes it will accept the IdentityServer Token as a Bearer Token?

Comment: yes you need to have a owin configured and IAppBuilder method has an extension method called "UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication" with required scopes and authority (your server url).

IdentityServer can give you authtoken if you say your response_type as "token" and your response token type can be of type bearer or pop.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan can you add a glance of the code where you are creating JWT tokens ?